# CSS não funcionando no meu HTML

Tags: html, css, front-end

O meu background feito em CSS, simplesmente, não está funcionando no meu HTML. A ideia era ter um background preto atrás do logo "World". Mas não está aparecendo. Já tentei ver se o problema era a cor. Até mudei ela, mas também não mudou nada. Também mudei a pasta onde está o arquivo HTML e CSS e também não consegui. O que há de errado com o meu código?

[logotipo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaQMj.png)

```css
.header-1 {
    background-color:#252323;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <Title> Primeiro Projeto </Title>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="menu principal">
    <div class="header-1"></div>
       <div class="logo"> 
        <img src="./img/logo.png">
       </div>
    <div class="redes sociais"></div>
   </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Como disse que a resposta do Jonas Lima não o atende está difícil de entender o que quer. Veja se é isso, no css troque `.header-1 { background-color:#252323;}` por `header { background-color:#252323;}`

Comment: Também de uma conferida no caminho passado em `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` e o caminho do css.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente checar o caminho do arquivo style.css se está correto.

Uma "solução temporária e rápida" até que consiga corrigir esse problema seria codar seu CSS dentro do HTML segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
<html>
<head>
   <Title> Primeiro Projeto </Title>
   <style>
     .header-1 {
       background-color:#252323;
     }
   </style>

</head>
<body>
   <header class="menu principal">
    <div class="header-1"></div>
       <div class="logo"> 
        <img src="./img/logo.png">
       </div>
    <div class="redes sociais"></div>
   </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você está fechando a div na linha onde se encontra sua classe 'header-1'. Para aplicar esse style, você deve manter os elementos filhos dentro da div onde está a class.
Ficando da seguinte forma

```css
.header-1 {
    background-color:#252323;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <Title> Primeiro Projeto </Title>
</head>

<body>
   <header class="menu principal">
      <div class="header-1">
         <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/logo.png">
         </div>
         <div class="redes sociais"></div>
      </div>
   </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O problema continua :/. Copiei e colei o seu código e não funcionou. Executei em outro browser e também naõ foi.

Comment: Verifique o caminho do seu arquivo css

Answer (score -2):

A div **header-1** estava fechando na mesma linha e dentro dela não tinha conteúdo algum.

basta fechar a div após o fechando da div **logo**.

Espero ter ajudado! ;)

```css
.header-1 {
    background-color:#252323;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <Title> Primeiro Projeto </Title>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="menu principal">
    <div class="header-1">
       <div class="logo"> 
           <img src="./img/logo.png">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="redes sociais"></div>
   </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Parece que você está tentando adicionar uma cor de fundo ao elemento "div" com a classe "header-1", mas ela não está aparecendo no seu HTML. Alguns possíveis problemas que podem estar causando esse comportamento incluem:

1. Verifique se você está chamando o arquivo CSS corretamente no HTML. Certifique-se de que o caminho para o arquivo CSS está correto e que o arquivo CSS realmente existe na pasta especificada.
2. Verifique se você está aplicando a classe "header-1" corretamente no elemento "div". Certifique-se de que a classe está escrita corretamente e que está sendo aplicada ao elemento "div" correto.
3. Verifique se o seu código CSS está sendo escrito corretamente. Certifique-se de que você está usando o seletor correto para o elemento "div" e que a sintaxe do código CSS está correta.
4. Verifique se o seu navegador está atualizado. Às vezes, problemas de visualização podem ser causados por problemas de compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos.

Se você verificou todos esses itens e ainda está tendo problemas, tente adicionar um "height" e um "width" ao seu elemento "div" para garantir que ele tenha dimensões visíveis. Isso pode ajudar a mostrar o fundo na tela.

```
.header-1 {
background-color:#252323;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

As vezes acontece comigo e o problema está no cache do navegador, tenta ir nas configurações e limpar os dados de navegação.